# Type hinting/specifying a type in lua

Tags: types, lua, type-hinting, code-hinting

There's a feature in python where you can
specify a type of a variable or a function
argument or something, but I'm doing some lua
right now I'd like to specify a type as my
auto completion shows type any so I thought lua
might also have that feature

Basically I have a function called log:

```lua
local function log(message)
    io.stderr:write(string.format(" :: %s\n", message))
end
```

Is there a way to specify the type of arg `message`
and/'or at least' the return type?
I want it to be a string :)

In python it'd be:

```py
import sys

def log(message: str) -> None:
    sys.stderr.write(f" :: {message}\n")
```

Comment: What exactly would you want to happen if you passed something other than a string as `message`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica to be honest I don't mind it, I would at least like it to be there for easier linting and stuff but an error is also fine, I don't mind anything happening, any solution works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua does not support type annotations. Your options are the following:

1. Use a Lua preprocessor like [TS2Lua](https://github.com/TypeScriptToLua/) or [Teal](https://github.com/teal-language/) which supports types
2. Use `assert`s to check argument types, throwing a runtime error if they don't match: `assert(type(message) == "string")`; you can also use an `assert(select("#", ...) == 0)` to check the arity if you add an additional vararg param `...` to the argument list
3. Use comments to document types inline, possibly in combination with a documentation generator that support your annotations: `local function log(message --[[string]]) --> nothing`

Answer (score 10):

Lua handles variable types dynamically which is why there are no required annotations. You can, however, explicitly state the type of a variable with the following syntax:

```lua
---@type integer
local x = 3
```

This is entirely optional. Doing so could improve readability as this is built into the documentation and is also recognized by many IDE's with syntax highlighting.

[image]